# select the records that doesn't get joined along with those that are joined

Tags: mysql

Hi there i have two tables in below format:

A Table:

```
  ID   |  columnx | event |
  1    |     4    | call  |
  2    |     7    | call  |
  3    |     4    | call  |
  4    |     11   | visit |
```

B  Table:

```
columnx  | fName |
  4      | clare |
  7      | Bill  |
  9      | Tom   |
  11     | Nick  |
```

I made a query as follows:

```
Select A.columnx ,B.fName,Count(event) as Calls
from A
Left Join B on A.columnx = B.columnx 
where 'event' LIKE 'call';
```

It gave output as follows :

```
 columnx | fname  | Calls|
    4     | Clare  |   2  |
    7     | Bill   |   1  |
    11    | Nick   |   0  |
```

But how can i get the below output:

```
 columnx  | fname  | Calls|
    4     | Clare  |   2  |
    7     | Bill   |   1  |
    11    | Nick   |   0  |
    9     | Tom    |   0  |
```

I mean when a particular record doesn't get joined still i need to select the record with count as 0. can this be done with join or do i need to find an another way. Any suggestions. Thank You.

Comment: Not possible, because you're requiring that all returned records have a "call" event. people who have no call events will not be returned.you'd have to remove the `where` clause.

Comment: if you drop `where 'event' LIKE 'call';` - should do the trick

Comment: You might need to change from a left join to a right join. (I always get these two confused, but considering you are currently getting Nick with no Tom in the results, my guess is you used the wrong kind of join).

Comment: @Elen I cant drop it because i need to count the number of calls under  each record.Thats the main intent of query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `count()` of the calls:

```
select dv.columnx,
  dv.fname,
  coalesce(dl.calls, 0) Calls
from device dv
left join
(
  select count(dl.event) Calls, dl.columnx
  from deal dl
  where dl.event LIKE 'call'
  group by dl.columnx
) dl
  on dv.columnx = dl.columnx
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50924/7).

Or this can be done without a subquery by moving the `WHERE` filter to the `JOIN`:

```
select dv.columnx,
  dv.fname,
  coalesce(count(dl.event), 0) Calls
from device dv
left join deal dl
  on dv.columnx = dl.columnx
  and dl.event LIKE 'call'
group by dv.columnx,  dv.fname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50924/8)

This returns:

```
| COLUMNX | FNAME | CALLS |
---------------------------
|       4 | clare |     2 |
|       7 |  Bill |     1 |
|       9 |   Tom |     0 |
|      11 |  Nick |     0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Move  'event' LIKE 'call' to additional contition of left join

```
    Select B.columnx ,B.fName ,Count(A.'event') as Calls
    from A
    Right Join B on A.columnx   = B.columnx   and A.'event' LIKE 'call'
    group by B.columnx  ,B.fName 
    order by B.columnx
```

Comment: use only columns off B on select and change  From table to b and left join to A or use a right join